# vue3: Array props pass via router

Tags: vue-router, vuejs3

I have a quite huge object to pass from the first page to the second page. The operation is to click an icon on an echart object & display the details in the detailedView page
This is my "from" page - and the tableData.value contained the large object to be displayed in the detailed page

```
  const router = useRouter();

  onclick: function (){
                     router.push({name:"DetailedView", params:{ title:"My Detail", tableData:tableData.value}});
                }
```

This is my "to" page - the el-table is to display the data

```
<template>
<label>Detailed Data View For {{title}}</label>
 <el-table
    :data="tableData"
    >
</el-table>    
</template>
<script lang="ts">
export default defineComponent({
        name: "DetailedView",
        props: [
         "title",
        
         "tableData"
          
         ],
        setup(props, { attrs, slots, emit }){
...
```

The "title" props has been passed successfully however the "tableData" hasn't
Can you please advise what's the problem?

Comment: What is the value of `tableData.value`? And what does the component see it as in the `tableData` prop?

Comment: Hello Tony, tableData.value is a large array and below is a snippet of the data: [{"metricscope": "EMEA",  "count": 30, "asof": "2020-05"}, {"metricscope": "EMEA", "count": 54, "asof": "2020-06"}]. When I passed the value via props, I received empty array [] in the destination page.